# AWS s3 ( blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check) when try to upload an image from react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and wanted to use aws s3 to store the images when uploaded from my react app, i created the bucket and used the following
cors policy

```
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

and my bucket policy as follow

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicListGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i keep getting CORS error and i am not sure why
This is my error message

```
bucket_name.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:4000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

```
let config = {
        bucketName: 'bucket_name',
        region: 'us-west-1',
        accessKeyId: 'key',
        secretAccessKey: 'secret_key',
        s3Url:'https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/',
  }
```

```
function upload(e){
  S3FileUpload.uploadFile(e.target.files[0],config)
  .then((data)=>console.log(data.location))
  .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
}
```

Can someone here point me to right direction?

Edit- Now i am getting this bad request error
[Bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgQro.png)

Edit 2 - I figured out the solution i had to create the access point on my Bucket and it worked.

Comment: I think you are missing the `s3:Put*` in `Action` block, can you add it ad try again?

Comment: @JuanFontes i added s3:Put* in my Action but it's still giving me the cors error but now i am getting the bad request error, i have added the image of the error in my edit